# QWebEngine does nothing - no page loaded, no error

Tags: qt, qt5, qtwebengine, qt5.5

I'm trying to load a locally stored webpage with QWebEngine:

```
m_browser = new QWebEngineView( this );
QWebEngineSettings *settings = m_browser->page()->settings();
settings->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::JavascriptEnabled, true);
settings->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::AutoLoadImages, true);
settings->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::ErrorPageEnabled, true);    
...
m_browser->load(QUrl(myURL));
```

The code was ported from QWebKit where everything worked fine. Unfortunately nothing happens here, the page is not loaded, no loadStarted() and no loadFinished() signal is emitted and no other error occurs.

Any idea what the reason could be or what I could check to find the reason for why it does not load anything?

Thanks!

Comment: I posted an answer but now I'm not sure about the solution. `load` should open the url. Anyway, try `m_browser->show();`

Comment: Tarod: thanks for answering but that does not change anything...

Comment: That snippet of code is OK. The window where `m_browser` is being instantiated is also shown? Could you share with us more code related to `m_browser`? Do you know this Qt [example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebenginewidgets-fancybrowser-mainwindow-cpp.html)? Is working in your environment?

Comment: Tarod: yes, the window is shown to. More than this, the whole code worked well with QWebKit, I only changed the include and class names to migrate to QWebEngine - that's all, no functional changes!

Comment: add `qDebug() << QUrl(myURL);` below `m_browser->load` and add it to the question. It's possible that your URL is invalid and webkit was more tolerant of it than chromium is.

Comment: Kuba Ober: this returns QUrl("file:///D:/Temp/Target/main/documentation/eng/GUI/Index_CSH.htm#InitDlg") which seems to be a vlid URL (and that works fine when I use it on my local webbrowser.